# Not understanding the FAIL/PASS in casperjs

Tags: casperjs

I am using casperjs/phantomjs with this code

```
casper.test.begin('assertEquals() tests', 3, function(test) {
    test.assertEquals(1 + 1, 3);
    test.assertEquals([1, 2, 3], [1]);
    test.assertEquals({a: 1, b: 2}, {a: 1, b: 4});
    test.done();
});
```

In the console I get Failed tests as expected but what I can't understand is why the test suite is marked as PASS

```
PASS assertEquals() tests (3 tests)
FAIL 1 test executed in 0.029s, 0 passed, 1 failed, 0 dubious, 0 skipped.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't regonized that before like this, but you also get the Error-Messages of the failing (first) equal. 
The **last PASS** is just saying that casperjs is **finished** with the **testsuite**, no matter what is failing inside the suite.

This is the full log:

```
    root@4332425a143d:/casperjs# casperjs test test.js
    Test file: test.js
    # assertEquals() tests
    FAIL Subject equals the expected value
    #    type: assertEquals
    #    file: test.js
    #    subject: 2
    #    expected: 3
    PASS assertEquals() tests (3 tests)
    FAIL 1 test executed in 0.025s, 0 passed, 1 failed, 0 dubious, 0 skipped.
```

So that says that the first equals fails and the suite "assertEquals()" finished.